# Is it possible to do a conditional aggregation in Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, hibernate

I am using Spring and MongoDB with MongoTemplate.

I have this document:

```
{
  price: 50.0,
  goal: {
       currentValue: 20,
       goal: 100
  }
}
```

I need to do a query such as "**bring me the values where its current value is the same as the goal**" or "**bring me the documents where its current value is 50% of its goal**".

Is it possible to do this? So far I've been doing this kind of queries but never did a conditional one where it uses the documents current values as part of the condition.

```
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("price").exists(true);

GroupOperation totalAggregation = group()
      .sum("goal.currentValue")
      .as("currentValue")
      .sum("goal.goal")
      .as("goal");
UnwindOperation unwind = unwind("$goal");
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(match(criteria), unwind, totalAggregation);

AggregationResults<Document> results = mongoTemplate
                .aggregate(aggregation,"Goals", Document.class);
```

Now I just want to bring the ones with the scenario that I described above only. How to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: which mongodb version are you using?

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti 4.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can use MongoDB 4.0.1, You can use `$expr` to get the desired result.

The required query will look like this :

```
db.criteria.find( { $expr: { $eq: [ "$goal.currentValue" , "$goal.goal" ] } } )
```

or, if you need current value as 50% of goal

```
db.criteria.find( { $expr: { $eq: [ "$goal.currentValue" , {divide : ["$goal.goal",2]} ] } } )
```

I dont know Spring, and how mongodb is used with Spring, thats why i gave the answer in Mongo Shell. You can write the syntax in Spring MongoTemplate. The idea is to use `$expr` to use document fields in match condition.

for more info read [MongoDB official $expr documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/).

**Update**:

MongoTemplate syntax for the same might look like this (not tested):

```
BasicQuery query1 = new BasicQuery("{ $expr: { $eq: [ '$goal.currentValue' , '$goal.goal' ] } }");
List<Document> = mongoOperation.find(query1, Document.class);
```

Give this a try, and tell me if there is some mistake in the above query. I just gave a try to write it in your required syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve this query: "bring me the values where its current value is the same as the goal" or "bring me the documents where its current value is 50% of its goal".

This can be done using $where operator where you can pass a JavaScript expression or a simple JavaScript function which specifies the condition that you want to evaluate.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/

Here is the sample query which I ran and gave me expected result:

```
db.getCollection("stackQues").find(
    {
      $or: [
                {$where: "this.goal.currentValue == this.goal.goal"}, 
                {$where: "this.goal.currentValue == this.goal.goal/2"}
            ]
    }
);
```

Comment: the thing is that i want to do this without having the goal and currentvalue previously stored

Comment: this answer is also correct, but you will find $where to be much more expensive than   $expr

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti Agree, $where does not use any predefined indexes